# Understanding String::Find In C++

Tags: c++, string, find

I've been given a programming task that involves taking away certain letters in a string. I was trying out different ways to do this when I found the public member function string find. To put it short I was testing out the function via this program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

  string Word = "Applejuice";
  
  cout<<Word.find("e")<<endl;






  return 0;


}
```

So when I put in a letter such as "e" I get the number 4 which confuses me because I thought the function will count all the letters in that specific word such as apple juice. Also, when I use a letter that is not used in that word I get numbers like 18446744073709551615 for example when I put in X for e in the code above.

Could someone explain why this is happening, please?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Comment: `find()` returns the index of the first occurrence it finds.  So, in your case, it returns the index of the first `'e'` in `"Apple"` which is `4`  (bearing in mind that indexing in C++ is zero-based, so the index of the `'A'` in `'Apple'` is `0`).     In future, try reading the documentation for functions you use, rather than assuming you know what they do - your assumption was completely wrong this time.

Comment: So how do I make it so it would count the numbers of time a certain letter was in a word? When does overflow happens?

Comment: `find()` doesn't count how many times it finds what it is searching for.   It only returns the index of the first one it finds (or `string::npos` if there is none to find).   If you want to count how many times the string is present, `find()` - at least on its own - is not the solution because it doesn't do counting.    If you want to use `find()` for that purpose, you need to implement the logic (e.g. a loop that calls `find()` repeatedly).

Comment: 1) You make an assumption about how something works, 2) You write some code based on that assumption, 3) The code doesn't work as you expected, 4) You say you don't understand. What stops you going back to step 1 and asking yourself whether the assumption you made was correct? It's not as if you don't have any evidence. You're by no means the only one, I see this failure of critical thinking among beginners quite often. It's something you have to get over, incorrect assumptions are a common cause of bugs.

Comment: @Mactin "*So how do I make it so it would count the numbers of time a certain letter was in a word?*" - you can use [`std::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) for that.

Answer (score 2):

`string.find()` will return the position of the first character of the first match.
If no matches were found, the function returns `string::npos`.

Therefore the number (18446744073709551615) you are getting is the `string::npos`

If you want to search for an only a single character in the string you can use the following code

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 
  
// Function that return count of the given  
// character in the string 
int count(string s, char c) 
{ 
    // Count variable 
    int res = 0; 
  
    for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++) 
  
        // checking character in string 
        if (s[i] == c) 
            res++; 
  
    return res; 
} 
  
// Driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    string str= "Applejuice"; 
    char c = 'e'; 
    cout << count(str, c) << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to avoid some random large values as output i.e. `string::npos` you can just add check for it like following:

```
 if(Word.find("e") != string::npos)
 {
    ...
 }
```

Comment: [std::basic_string::npos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) not `nopos` -- typo last paragraph/snippeet -- (but we know what you meant `:)`

Comment: For explanation: [`npos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) the maximum value of its type `std::string::size_type`, which is `std::size_t`...

Comment: No need to re-invent the wheel: There already is [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count): `auto n = std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), 'e');`

Answer (score 0):

Method find from class string return the position of the first character of the first match. Return type of find is size_t and since size_t is unsigned integral so if no match were found return string::nopos so you should compare the outputof find with string::nopos.

```
 if(Word.find("e") != string::nopos)
 {
    ...
 }
```

Comment: See *Return* section of [std::basic_string::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) paying close attention to `npos`.

Comment: No overflow! The odd number is the maximum value of size_t, as which `npos` is defined.

Comment: @Aconcagua you could check the definition of npos here  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos  is defined as -1  so convert to unsigned

Comment: Conversion of negative to unsigned is not overflow. There are clear rules how to perform that (adding maximum value + 1 until negative value fits into type – which for 2's complement effectively is a no-op).